# Drawer doesn't close after i pick an option

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

The Drawer open and fuction correctly. When i pick an option its change to the correct fragemnt but the drawer stays open. How cani fix it?

My MainActivity

```
package com.example.duolingo;

import static com.example.duolingo.R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.duolingo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private FrameLayout main_frame;
    private TextView drawerProfileName, drawerProfileText;

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener onNavigationItemSelectedListener=
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId())
                    {
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            setFragement(new CategoryFragment());
                            return true;

                        case R.id.nav_leaderboard:
                            setFragement(new LeaderBoardFragment());
                            return true;

                        case R.id.nav_account:
                            setFragement(new AccountFragment());
                            return true;


                    }
                    return false;
                }
        };

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
            setContentView(binding.getRoot());

            setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);

            bottomNavigationView=findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_bar);
            main_frame= findViewById(R.id.main_frame);

            bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener);


            DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
            NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
            Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
                menu should be considered as top level destinations.
                mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                        R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                stack overflow
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();


            drawerProfileName = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_name);
            drawerProfileText = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_text_img);

            String name = DbQuery.myProfile.getName();
            drawerProfileName.setText(name);

            drawerProfileText.setText(name.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT).substring(0,1));

            setFragement(new CategoryFragment());

            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, nav_host_fragment_content_main);
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        }

    private void setFragement(Fragment fragement)
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(main_frame.getId(),fragement);
        transaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
        public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, nav_host_fragment_content_main);
            return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                super.onSupportNavigateUp();
        }


    @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            Log.d("edo","mphka1");
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
                setFragement(new CategoryFragment());
                return true;
            }
            else if (id == R.id.nav_leaderboard) {
                Handle the gallery action
                    setFragement(new LeaderBoardFragment());
                return true;

            }
            else if (id == R.id.nav_account) {
                Handle the slideshow action
                    setFragement(new AccountFragment());
                return true;

            }



            DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            return true;
        }

    @Override
        public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {
            super.onPointerCaptureChanged(hasCapture);
        }
}
```

The content_main

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/main_background"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
 
 
     <fragment
 android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
 android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:defaultNavHost="true"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
 app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
 
     <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
 android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu">
 
     </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
 
     <FrameLayout
 android:id="@+id/main_frame"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
 
     </FrameLayout>
 
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If i click the home page the drawer closes. In my opinion is because of the fragment in the content_main.

Are those two lines correct?

```
DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting in your post. Please don't use blockquotes for code. Indent your code by four spaces instead, so that it's displayed properly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more info on formatting. Also, next time please indent your code appropriately so it's more readable. And finally, you're not supposed to dump your entire code in the question. You should post a [example], instead.

Comment: Ty very much sorry i am new to this

Answer (score 0):

if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
setFragement(new
CategoryFragment());
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

```
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).